# Creating a 32-bit Windows DLL using Zig without the C runtime and removing unnecessary exports

Tags: windows, dll, zig

I am new to the Zig language and have a question about creating a 32-bit Windows DLL.
I am using `zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2612+56d800ff7.zip`.

I have created a project using `zig init-lib`, but the generated `build.zig` seemed to be for a static library, so I ignored it.

To create a release build without debug information, I used the following command:

```
zig build-lib -O ReleaseFast -fstrip -target x86-windows-gnu -dynamic src/main.zig
```

However, this command produced several `undefined symbol` errors, such as:

```
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: _DllMainCRTStartup@12
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: add
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: _tls_index
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: _tls_start
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: _tls_end
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: __xl_a
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: __xl_z
error: lld-link: <root>: undefined symbol: _tls_used
```

Adding `-lc` to the options allowed the compilation to succeed, but I don't think this is the correct solution since Zig doesn't depend on the C runtime.
I want to know if there's a way to compile without the C runtime.

Additionally, inspecting the generated `main.dll` with `dumpbin /EXPORTS` shows that `_DllMainCRTStartup@12` is exported:

```
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 _DllMainCRTStartup@12 = __DllMainCRTStartup@12
          2    1 00001010 add = _add
```

I believe it is unnecessary as it's the DLL entry point and shouldn't be used by `GetProcAddress`.
Please tell me if there is a reason why this is being exported, or if there is a way to prevent it from being exported.

I discovered that commenting out the `@export` in `lib/std/start.zig` achieved the desired behavior, but obviously this is not a smart.
I'm looking for the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your build.zig for zig-lib change "addStaticLibrary" to "addSharedLibrary". Then run "zig build" to rebuild the library and now you will have a zig-lib.dll in .\zig-out\lib directory.

Laters,
SLDR

Comment: I edited the `build.zig` as you said and built with the `zig build -Dtarget=x86-windows-gnu -Doptimize=ReleaseFast`, but I got the same error.
After researching, this seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/11817).